# How to allow wider spacing between words within justification in order to prevent hyphenation

Tags: spacing, hyphenation

I have a document which has text in justification format. My text is about explaining something about hyphenation. That is why some examples I give should not automatically be hyphenated to fit the justification format. That is why I used `\mbox{}` around the text that should not be hyphenated in the following way:

```
However, in rare cases also compounds of three nouns are hyphenated. For example \mbox{``Brand- und Explosionsschutzbeauftragten''} is incorrectly resolved to ``\mbox{Brandbeauftragten} und \mbox{Explosionsschutzbeauftragten''}, ``Strom- und  \mbox{Wärmeerzeugungsanlagen''} to ``\mbox{Stromanlagen} und\mbox{Wärmeerzeugungsanlagen''}, or ``Konflikt- und \mbox{Problemlösungskompetenz''} to ``\mbox{Konfliktkompetenz} und \mbox{Problemlösungskompetenz}''. In these cases, the hyphen does not substitute only the last but the last two nouns of the regular noun.
```

However, that leads to such a formatting:

[image: the resulting formatting]

How can I evoke a formatting, such that for example a newline follows after 'und'. I can tolerate large spaces between words within a line, but I cannot tolerate any automatic hyphenation or extending the borders of the justification format. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\sloppy` allows the white space to stretch although with words that long and no hyphenation you may prefer `\raggedright`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for the quick reply, \sloppy works exactly as I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\sloppy` allows the white space to stretch more than the default (`\fussy`) setting,